# How to use findOne() method of CRUDRepository using Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, repository

I want to use the `findOne()` method of `CRUDRepository`, but unable to use it.

I am using the `CRUDRepository` for Persistence. I checked the CRUDRepository, but the `findOne()` method is not available. When I searched Javadoc of CRUDRepository it shows `findOne()` method is there.

```java
@Override
    public MultiplicationResultAttempt getResultById(Long resultId) {

        return attemptRepository.findOne(resultId);
    }
```

Comment: If you are using a recent version of Spring Data use `findById` instead of `findOne`.

Comment: but it returns an Optional and I didn't require to use Optional. Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Use the optional, `repo.findById(id).orElse(null)` to mimic the classic behavior. Although I would suggest using an `Optional`.

Comment: Ok, I will try the above snippet.

Comment: @farhanlq: but it returns an Optional and I didn't require to use Optional. Is there any other way to do that? -> Override method findOne in your own custom repository so that it will never return an Optional, but internally it will use the spring method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27950246/spring-data-overriding-default-methods-for-some-repositories

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`findOne` was replaced by `findById()` in `CRUD Repository`. See [DATACMNS-944](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-944)

Note that `findById` is not an exact replacement for `findOne`, it returns an `Optional` instead of `null`.

example usage:

```
@Override
public MultiplicationResultAttempt getResultById(Long resultId) {

   return attemptRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
}
```

Comment: So, If I can change the JPA dependency in pom.xml to an older version. Do you think it works?

Comment: yes it will work but i dont suggest doing that, whats your reason for not using an optional? the above example is exactly the same behavior you expect from `findOne`

Comment: Just changing the Spring Data JPA version won't work. It has a minimal Spring dependency and thus also requires you to downgrade your Spring version, which n turn might you to downgrade your other libraries as well.

Comment: @Mustahsan. Thanks, now I used your above snippet and it works according to my expectation.

Comment: @M.Deinum. now I am using the FindById(). Thanks to both of you for immediate response.

Comment: @farhanlq you're welcome, you can consider marking the answer as accepted if this helped your cause.